# notifying id token listeners about user flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, email, identity

543 / 5 000
Résultats de traduction
I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a login page with firebase but the problem is that when I put my email + my password I have this message that appears 'Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System (30113): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(30113): Notifying id token listeners about user ( gZ4NEwxh0qRRl32ypTGvqgX6kJx2 ).' I connected firebase to my application and I put the authentication by mail, I added the sha1 and the sha-256.

```
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());

}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  get crossAxisAlignment => crossAxisAlignment;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: FirstPage(),





   );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:untitled/connexion.dart';
import 'package:untitled/home.dart';



class MainPage extends StatelessWidget{
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);








  Widget build(BuildContext context){





  return Scaffold(
    body:StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
          return HomePage();
        } else{
          return LloginScreen1();
        }

      }
    )


  );
 }
}
```

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:delayed_display/delayed_display.dart';

import 'services/auth.dart';












class LloginScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const LloginScreen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LloginScreen1> createState() => _LloginScreen1();
}

class _LloginScreen1 extends State<LloginScreen1> {

  Authservices auth = Authservices();


    final _emailController = TextEditingController();
    final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
    final _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges();






    Future signIn() async{
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailController.text.trim(),
          password: _passwordController.text.trim(),

      );
    }



    @override
    void dispose(){
      _emailController.dispose();
      _passwordController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }




    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(



        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
                child: DelayedDisplay(
                    delay: Duration(milliseconds: 5),
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 100),
                          Image.asset(
                            "images/nutrisport.png", width: 300, height: 200,),
                          SizedBox(width: 330,
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _emailController,

                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                                    hintText: "Email",
                                    border:
                                    OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            32.0))),


                              )
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),

                          SizedBox(width: 330,
                              child: TextField(
                                obscureText: true,
                                controller: _passwordController,


                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Icon(
                                         Icons.visibility_off
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    border:
                                    OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            32.0))),
                              ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 50,),


                          SizedBox(height:55,
                            width: 330,
                            child:ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text('Connexion',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),),
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color.fromARGB(
                                      200, 119, 141, 67)),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                              onPressed: signIn,

                            ),),


                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text('Mot de passe oublié ?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.cyan
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])))));
  }
}
```